# How to draw multiple images on the same form at the one time

Tags: c#

this is a follow-up question about a problem I'm having in the same project:
In my graphics method(I'm using this as the update method) I'm drawing a map image that I have stored locally in the debug folder. However when a certain area on the map is clicked the map should go away and be replaced by 3 images. However I'm having the problem that only one image at a time(the last one) is actually being drawn. Here is my graphics method anyway:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        //load the map image
        Image map = Image.FromFile("map.png");
        SolidBrush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

         //now I need to add the paint controls for is hit and not hit
        if (isHit == true && goBack == false)
        {
            g.DrawImage(backButton, new Point(0, 0));
            for (int i = 0; i < trees.Length; i++)
            {
                if (trees[i].isHit == true)
                {   
                    Tree t = trees[i];
                    Image treeImage1, treeImage2;
                    treeImage1 = Image.FromFile(t.EnglishName + ".png");
                    treeImage2 = Image.FromFile(t.EnglishName + "leaf.png");
                    g.DrawImage(treeImage1, new Point(10,20);
                    g.DrawImage(treeImage2, new Point((treeImage1.Width + 10), 20);
                    loadTree(trees[i]);                        
                }
            }
            //update labels for text and info                 
            // draw a back button(add control to click, use image)
        }
        else if(isHit == false)
        {
            g.DrawImage(backButton, new Point(0, 0));
            g.DrawImage(map, new Point(0, 0));

            for (int i = 0; i < trees.Length; i++)
            {
                g.FillRectangle(b, trees[i].X, trees[i].Y, 3, 3);

            }

        }
        this.Refresh();

    }
```

One problem I have found so far is that this first if statement is never reached whenever the statement is true(for some unknown reason)
These variables are controlled in my mouse click event as follows:

```
    private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        mouseX = e.X;
        mouseY = e.Y;
        bool isClicked = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < trees.Length; i++)
        {
            isClicked = trees[i].checkClick(mouseX, mouseY);
            if (isClicked)
            {
                isHit = isClicked;
                if(mouseX >= 5 && mouseX <= backButton.Width)
                {                        
                    if(mouseY >= 5 & mouseY <= backButton.Height)
                    {
                        goBack = true;
                        trees[i].isHit = false;
                        isHit = false;
                        HideLabels();
                    }
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < trees.Length; j++) 
                {
                    if (trees[j] != trees[i]) 
                    {
                        trees[j].isHit = false;
                    }
                }
                trees[i].isHit = true;
                loadTree(trees[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. If you need more info please let me know and I'll post it up a.s.a.p
Thanks :)

Comment: Do not call `Refresh()` in a paint handler.

Comment: You should read the image files once (in your ctor) rather than doing all that work on every repaint

Comment: @SLaks they will be done that way. I merely have them commented them and wrote them in the paint region.

Answer (score 0):

"However I'm having the problem that only one image at a time(the last one) is actually being drawn."

In your hit routine, whenever a tree is hit, you go through and reset all the others with this loop:

```
            for (int j = 0; j < trees.Length; j++) 
            {
                if (trees[j] != trees[i]) 
                {
                    trees[j].isHit = false;
                }
            }
```

Therefore only the last hit tree will be true.

We have no idea what your system looks like (or how it should behave), but a possible solution is to use that loop ONCE, BEFORE checking all the trees so they all start out as false and only the hit ones get toggled.  Maybe something like:

```
private void Form1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // reset all the trees:
    for (int j = 0; j < trees.Length; j++) 
    {
        trees[j].isHit = false;
    }

    // see which trees are hit:
    mouseX = e.X;
    mouseY = e.Y;
    bool isClicked = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < trees.Length; i++)
    {
        isClicked = trees[i].checkClick(mouseX, mouseY);
        if (isClicked)
        {
            // initially true, but might be reset below if the 
            // back button was hit instead?
            trees[i].isHit = true;

            isHit = isClicked;
            if(mouseX >= 5 && mouseX <= backButton.Width)
            {                        
                if(mouseY >= 5 & mouseY <= backButton.Height)
                {
                    goBack = true;
                    trees[i].isHit = false;
                    isHit = false;
                    HideLabels();
                }
            }

            loadTree(trees[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A good solution to the click problems. However if you notice in the paint method the booleans from the trees.isHit property is controlling whether the image is displayed or not. So if a person misclicks by accident then the images will not be drawn. The only way the treeImages should be wiped off the screen is if the backbutton is clicked.

Comment: Well...as I said, we have no idea how your app is supposed to **behave**, it's really hard to discern that from a tiny portion of the code.  At any rate, you were resetting **all** of the trees except the currently "hit" one with that loop.  You'll have to figure out how best to use that information...

Comment: After debugging the code I have found the conditions inside where it's checking if the back button is clicked. I.e:

     if (mouseX >= 5 && mouseX <= backButton.Width)
    {
    if (mouseY >= 5 & mouseY <= backButton.Height)
    {
       goBack = true;
       trees[i].isHit = false;
       isHit = false;
       HideLabels();
     }
   }
is always being hit. This seems to me to be a minor mismanagement of the collision detection I'm using but I cannot see what is wrong with it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually in the line where it is drawing the back button. The canvas wasn't scaled down and it was set larger than the application is so it'll always be true unless you maximise the application. After cropping it successfully everything works as it should with my original methods